# What percentage of introns are spliced in polyadenylated mRNAs?

Tags: splicing

I am asking a variation of a previously asked question: [What percentage of RNA splicing happens during transcription?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/88851/what-percentage-of-rna-splicing-happens-during-transcription)

I am planning mRNA purification using poly(A) antisense-oligo pull-down and, for subsequent purposes, would need to have an educated guess on what percentage of introns I should expect to be spliced out. An easier alternative question, mitigating the complication of mRNA turnover, would be the percentage of introns that are spliced until completion of polyadenylation.

Maybe someone knows more recent papers on this?

Comment: I mean the an answer for an average mRNA independent of concentrations. I will self-answer once I find a good estimate.

Comment: Might depend somewhat on the organism, whether the retained introns are part of "mature" alternative mRNAs vs. incompletely spliced mRNAs, whether cell compartment matter, etc. For example, [Arabidopsis has lots of unspliced introns in polyadenylated nuclear transcripts that are absent from cytoplasm](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41477-020-0688-1), with a report of >50% of introns being removed post-transcriptionally (apparently some of these are spliced before polyadenylation).

Comment: Introns are usually very huge compared to exons. If unspliced introns are worrying you, you could use size exclusion columns or PAGE to purify your RNA, if that helps.